# how to make 3scale sigle sign on to redirect to plan page?

Tags: 3scale

I want to redirect the user directly to plan subscription page with plan selected , so how can i do that .

If you can tell me how to read a parameter plan id from sso that will he help as well.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far / post your current code?

Comment: I have a website where i have a subscribe button, i want the user to be taken to 3scale on clicking on that button , and i want to pass the plan_id so that i will only show the selected plan to the user, then he pay for the plan and i will take him back to the site.

Answer (score 1):

To read the plan ID you can use the following Liquid tag: `{{ plan | to_param }}` when you already have access to the plan attribute from the *Application* object. This is used if you are doing a signup directly from the plan subscription page. Alternatively you can use `application[plan_id]={{plan.id}}` if you just want to maintain the plan ID in the query params upon redirect.

If you want the plan ID from your external site then you will need to use the 3scale APIs to retrieve this data so that the `plan.system_name` or `plan.id` can be passed in the redirect to the 3scale Developer Portal. Equally if these plans are fairly static then you could just hardcode them into the HTML.

When the user lands on the Developer Portal page there will need to be some custom Liquid that reads the query params and then filters the plans available:

```
{% assign params = request.request_uri | split: 'plan_id=' %}
{% param = params[1] %}

{% for service in provider.services %}
 {% for plan in service.application_plan %}
 {% case plan.id %}
 {% when param %}

Some HTML here that renders the subscription form to that plan.

 {% endcase %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The Liquid is very flexible so there are many ways you can do the same thing.

Check out the [Liquid Reference documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_3scale/2.saas/html/developer_portal/liquid-reference#applicationplan-drop) for more information on the *Application Plan Drop*.